# How can I get property from Laravel Illuminate\Support\Collection?

Tags: laravel-5, php-7

I'm trying to property from collections, but I can't do this.

I have this query:

```
$calls = collect(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   DB::select("SELECT count(id)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               FROM calls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
               WHERE started_at >= '" . $date . "' AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                     linked_id IS NULL")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          );
```

And as the result I got this

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#82146
     all: [
       {#1097
         +"count": 15,
       },
     ],
   }
```

How can I get this "count"? I've tried to

```
$calls->count
$count = get_object_vars($calls)
```

but in first case I have: 
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$count on line 1
and in the second I got empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, Please give alias to "count(id) as calls_count"

Here is your query.

```
$calls = collect(DB::select("SELECT count(id) as calls_count FROM calls WHERE started_at >= '" . $date . "' AND linked_id IS NULL"));
```

Here are few ways to get value of count now.

1.)

```
echo $calls[0]->calls_count;
```

2.)

```
$calls = $calls->first();
echo $calls->calls_count;
```

3.)

```
echo $calls->pluck('calls_count')->first()
```

**(I prefer this)**

Hope this help, Let me know i comment, if any doubt.